# A proper perspective of surface

Tags: geometry

I wonder if a surface should be regarded as a function defined on a manifold or as a submanifold. I find most answers perfer the latter.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Most answers for what? Submanifold with respect to what? In which context? In my experience you'd usually simply consider surfaces as manifolds (of dimension 2) in themselves rather than as functions on some other (sub)manifold.

Comment: Thank you, umm, actually, I don't have much experience with manifolds, but my textbook says that manifolds are generalized Euclid spaces, and a surface is a subset of Euclid spaces; I wonder if a manifold is a thing more like a container than an object. I find it hard to analyze surfaces by regarding them as manifold. umm, I should have a closer study.

Comment: I think considering them objects rather than containers is more intuitive - I'll add an answer regarding how you might think about manifolds and surfaces as manifolds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a somewhat wrong intuition about manifolds. I'll try to explain:

The intuition about manifolds is that they're *locally euclidean*.
What this really means is best explained with an example:

We live on the surface of earth which is of course a curved surface; but for us - locally - the earth's surface *looks* like a (euclidean) plane. The ground we're walking on can be modeled quite well with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the space we're moving through by $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we draw a small triangle on the ground then this triangle seems to obey all the rules of euclidean geometry.

This captures two important points:

- The *topology* of our space is locally euclidean: globally we live on a sphere (more or less) so if we keep moving in any direction we'll get back to where we started. This is of course not true for the euclidean plane. However locally if we take a patch of our ground and model it by a patch of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we don't have to make any "weird" changes that'd modify the topology in any way. We don't have to introduce or close any holes in the space etc.. Contrast this to earth as a whole: to turn the full earth into a piece of $\mathbb{R}^2$ you'd have to tear a whole to flatten it out somehow.
- We can locally use *euclidean geometry*: if we draw a triangle in the sand then that triangle has (at least if we measure it with reasonable accuracy) an inner angle sum of $180^°$. Lay a ruler on the ground and you can measure the sides of the triangle just fine. Constrast this again to earth as a whole: draw a triangle by moving from the north pole to the equator, walking along the equator a quarter of earth's circumference and moving back up to the north pole. This is a triangle with three $90^°$ angles: it doesn't obey the rules of euclidean geometry. If you try to measure it with a very long ruler you'll run into problems because the ruler bends away from earth.

So this is really what manifolds are about:

- There is some natural number $n$ such that around any point of the space, its topology is that of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (topological manifolds).
- This locally euclidean structure is somehow *smooth* - we can do calculus on the space (differentiable / smooth manifolds).
- There is some way to locally measure lengths and angles and these measurements vary smoothly as we move across the manifold (Riemannian manifolds).

One possible way to define surfaces is now to consider them topological / differentiable / riemannian (depending on what you wanna do) manifolds that locally behave like $\mathbb{R}^2$. Note how in this view earth is just earth - it's some abstract thing. It's in particular not a collection of numbers or something like that - even though we can (and often times want to) assign each point some numbers based on whatever coordinate system we choose.

Note how this definition is intrinsic: if we consider the surface of earth as a manifold then we don't care about how this surface is really embedded into 3D space etc. It's a standalone object. We can talk about the surface of earth without referencing earth's relative position to the sun, the center of our galaxy or whatever.

To learn more about the basics of this stuff you might enjoy Weeks' *the shape of space* as an informal introduction to the topological side or Needham's book on differential geometry for the geometry side. If you wanna get a bit more formal Fortney's *Visual Introduction to differential forms and calculus on manifolds* is a superb place to start.